# Flutter load json data on start

Tags: flutter, dart

My problem is that, before showing the screen. It should load the necessary data while displaying a splashscreen.

It works fine, until it goes to the create provider, the data which has been loaded into the list is getting cleared due to the list getting recreated. I wonder how can i tackle this? How should i load the data (json) file into the list instead.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<void> loadJson;

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadJson = QuestionProvider().loadJsonFiles();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: loadJson,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const MaterialApp(home: Splash());
        } else {
          return MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider<QuestionProvider>(create: (_) => QuestionProvider()),
            ],
            child: MaterialApp(
              title: "MyApp",
              theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
              ),
              home: const Home(),
            )
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class QuestionProvider with ChangeNotifier {
    final List<QuestionModel> questionList = <QuestionModel>[];
  
    Future<void> loadJsonFiles() async {
        final String response = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/questions.json");
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = await jsonDecode(response);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            questionList.add(QuestionModel.fromJson(data[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not invert the future builder and the providers?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiProvider(
    [...],
    child: Builder(
      builder: (context) => 
        FutureBuilder(
          future: Provider.of<QuestionProvider>().loadJsonFiles,
          child: [...]
        ),
    ),
  );
}
```

There may or may not be some disadvantages to this method, specifically, the value of the future is no longer cached, if this worries you, I recommend you cache the value within the `QuestionProvider` class itself.